# I am unable to install node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-run

```
Node version: v12.18.0
Npm version: 6.14.4
```

I deleted node_modules folder. Run command `npm cache clean --force` and then `npm install`. I get following error:

```
npm ERR! Exit status 9009
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-05T14_49_19_539Z-debug.log
```

when I run command `npm run watch`, I get following error:

```
npm ERR! @ watch: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 9009
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ watch script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I also deleted `package.lock` file and try again with `npm install` command but no luck.

here is my `package.json`

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^2.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.12"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ajv": "^6.5.0",
        "algoliasearch": "^3.27.1",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.3.5",
        "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
        "pusher-js": "^4.2.2",
        "vue": "^2.5.7",
        "vue-moment": "^3.2.0",
        "vue-select": "^2.4.0"
    }
}
```

I am scratching my head for hours but could not getting any solution. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: From where you are using command prompt? Are you using from any editor?

Comment: Did you checked cross-env  is installed in  global node modules

Comment: @turivishal yes I am using visual studio code

Comment: @HarrisKhan Please try using external command prompt and if possible open as administrator rights, because some times visual code cause the may reason of problem.

Comment: @MuniKumar I have seen, cross-env file is located in node_modules/dist/bin folder

Comment: npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! path C:\xampp\htdocs\partner-portal\node_modules\.staging\acorn-67abb6af\CHANGELOG.md
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\xampp\htdocs\partner-portal\node_modules\.staging\acorn-67abb6af\CHANGELOG.md' @turivishal receiving that error on open command prompt using admin right

Comment: first remove your `node_modules` folder and then after you can install again.

Comment: remove folder, clean cache, and then run npm install but still no luck

Comment: replace 'node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'  with 'webpack' and try